# System Resources Exceeded - Passthrough Query and VBA in Ms Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have written the below code which imports an excel file into an Access database, takes all the purchase order numbers from it, throws them into the criteria of a query, passes this criteria to a passthrough query, and then executes the query.  All works fine if the number of POs is limited, but when there are many, the system returns the error *System Resources Exceeded* when passing the criteria to the query definition.  The funny thing is that the actual query criteria (no matter how many POs) does however get passed to the query, but the script execution halts.

In consideration that I cannot create tables in the underlying Oracle database (ideally I could create a table with the PO numbers and do a join), any ideas on what I could do to improve my script and avoid this error?

Thank you.

```vb
Public Function ImportGoodPOs()
On Error GoTo ImportGoodPOs_Err

'This function imports the spreadsheet with te POs
Dim tbl As String, fd As FileDialog, fn As String, qry As String, tbl1 As String, tbl2 As String, db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, qString As String, qdExtData As QueryDef, qry2 As String, pos As String, sql As String
tbl = "tbl_TempPos"
tbl2 = "tbl_PoNumbers"
qry = "qry_GoodPosWithVendorDetails"
qry2 = "qry_GoodsPosWithVendorDetailsPQ"
tbl1 = "tbl_GoodPosWithVendorDetails"
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.AllowMultiSelect = False

MsgBox "Browse for the PO file to import...", vbOKOnly, "Attention!"

If fd.Show = True Then
    If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
        fn = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
Else
    'Exit code if no file is selected
    End
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tbl
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , tbl, fn, -1

' setting a dummy query definition to avoid future errors
sql = "SELECT APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 FROM APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL WHERE APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 = '201410377'"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qry2).sql = sql

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tbl)
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT " & tbl & ".[PO Number]"
sql = sql & "INTO " & tbl2 & " "
sql = sql & "FROM " & tbl

DoCmd.RunSQL sql

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tbl2)

rst.MoveFirst
pos = rst("PO Number")
qString = "(APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 = '" & pos & "')"

For X = 2 To rst.RecordCount
    rst.MoveNext
    pos = rst("PO Number")
    qString = qString & " OR (APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 = '" & pos & "')"
Next X

sql = "SELECT APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.PO_HEADER_ID, APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_LINE1, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_LINES_ALT, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_LINE2, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_LINE3, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CITY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.STATE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ZIP, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PROVINCE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.COUNTRY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.AREA_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PHONE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.FAX, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.FAX_AREA_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TELEX, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAYMENT_METHOD_LOOKUP_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_NUM, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_ACCOUNT_TYPE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TERMS_DATE_BASIS, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CURRENT_CATALOG_NUM, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.VAT_CODE, "
sql = sql & "APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.INVOICE_AMOUNT_LIMIT, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAY_DATE_BASIS_LOOKUP_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ALWAYS_TAKE_DISC_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.HOLD_ALL_PAYMENTS_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.HOLD_FUTURE_PAYMENTS_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.HOLD_REASON, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.HOLD_UNMATCHED_INVOICES_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.AP_TAX_ROUNDING_RULE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.AUTO_TAX_CALC_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.AUTO_TAX_CALC_OVERRIDE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.AMOUNT_INCLUDES_TAX_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EXCLUSIVE_PAYMENT_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TAX_REPORTING_SITE_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.VAT_REGISTRATION_NUM, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.OFFSET_VAT_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CHECK_DIGITS, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_NUMBER, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_LINE4, "
sql = sql & "APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.COUNTY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.ADDRESS_STYLE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_TRANSACTION_HANDLING, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_ID_NUMBER, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_PAYMENT_METHOD, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_PAYMENT_FORMAT, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_REMITTANCE_METHOD, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_CHARGE_BEARER, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EDI_REMITTANCE_INSTRUCTION, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.BANK_BRANCH_TYPE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAY_ON_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DEFAULT_PAY_SITE_ID, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAY_ON_RECEIPT_SUMMARY_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PCARD_SITE_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.MATCH_OPTION, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.FUTURE_DATED_PAYMENT_CCID, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CREATE_DEBIT_MEMO_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.OFFSET_TAX_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.SUPPLIER_NOTIF_METHOD, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.EMAIL_ADDRESS, "
sql = sql & "APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.REMITTANCE_EMAIL, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PRIMARY_PAY_SITE_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.SHIPPING_CONTROL, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.SELLING_COMPANY_IDENTIFIER, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.GAPLESS_INV_NUM_FLAG, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DUNS_NUMBER, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.RETAINAGE_RATE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_STATE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_PROVINCE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_COUNTY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_CITY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_ZIP, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.TCA_SYNC_COUNTRY, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.PAY_AWT_GROUP_ID, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CAGE_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.LEGAL_BUSINESS_NAME, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DOING_BUS_AS_NAME, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DIVISION_NAME, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.SMALL_BUSINESS_CODE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.CCR_COMMENTS, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DEBARMENT_START_DATE, APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.DEBARMENT_END_DATE "
sql = sql & "FROM APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL INNER JOIN APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL ON (APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.VENDOR_ID = APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.VENDOR_ID AND APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.VENDOR_SITE_ID = APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.VENDOR_SITE_ID) "
sql = sql & "WHERE " & qString

qString = ""

CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qry2).sql = sql

sql = ""

DoCmd.OpenQuery qry2, acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery qry, acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.Close acQuery, qry2, acSaveYes
DoCmd.Close acQuery, qry, acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenTable tbl1, acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Do you really need to return ***all*** of those fields?  Have you tried `APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL.SEGMENT1 IN (<your first query>)`?  *(Instead of reading the results from one query to write a potentially huge second query?)*

Comment: Try IN (1,2,..) like matBailie said. Also this line does not make any sense: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tbl)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I have already tried the IN, which does not work when the number of POs is huge.  The IN clause has a limit in the number of characters.  Unfortunately I do need all those fields to be returned.

Comment: Things to try: (1) just to limit the query SQL: use table aliases. Use them in the SELECT and WHERE clauses. `qString = qString & " OR (h.SEGMENT1 = '" & pos & "')"`

Comment: (2) if that fails too: insert the PO numbers into a **local** table, remove the WHERE clause from the Pass-Through query, and join the local table with the query. Or run a fully local query on linked tables and the local table. It probably won't be fast, but it should at least work.

Comment: (3) Explain to $Manager$ that you *need* a new table in Oracle for the PO Numbers.

Comment: Addendum: How long is `sql` when it fails? `Debug.Print Len(sql)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am already using alises: prl is the alias for the full table name.  I have tried to shorten it to p only, but to no avail.  If I were to put the PO numbers in a local table, how would I join it inside a passthrough query which is run on the server?  The reason I went to passthrough queries is that I wanted to make the query fast (I used to have it as a local query, but it would just take too much time).  I guess I will try to get access to create a table on the server side.

Comment: Addendum: the len of the SQL was 335229.

Comment: @barattlo_67 I didn't suggest embedding all the values in the `IN()` clause, I see suggested putting your earlier QUERY there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using ODBC links to the Oracle `APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL` and `APPS.AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL` tables? You should have permissions to do that. This would bypass the problems associated with the passthrough query. Just join the ODBC linked tables to the PO Number table you derived from Excel.

(original answer)
I think Andre hit on the problem: Barattolo_67 reports the query is 335,229 characters long. Access specifications say the maximum query size is around 64,000 characters. So Barattolo_67 is clearly exceeding this limit, which is most likely the cause of the System Resources Exceeded error.

Note that the query returns only 89 fields, so that is not the problem. The SELECT part of the query is only 4,000 characters long. The big problem is the `WHERE` clause, which adds another 300,000 characters.

Comment: MatBailie, thanks for clarifying.  Now I get your suggestion.  I will try it tomorrow at the office.

Comment: MatBailie, I have tried the IN suggestion, but I am facing problems as the second query is a passthrough query, while the first one is a local query.  When I put the firts query inside the second one, Access tells me that i have an invalid table name, as it is looking for a local table on the server.  Or at least, this is my conclusion.

Comment: I can't test it, but I suspect that you can't join an Access local table to a passthrough query. Your choices include:
1) Get permission to make an Oracle local table that holds the POs you require. Make a view that returns the 89 columns you want.
2) Go back to your original local table function, and do it all in Access

Comment: kismert, thank you for your reply.  I have tested it, and can confirm that you cannot join an Access table to a passthrough query.  Doing it all in Access makes the whole thing too slow, and thus I would avoid.

Comment: Of course you can join an Access table to a Pass-Through query. Create a new query, add the table and the Pass-Through query, create the join. Done. What you cannot do is use anything local from Access **inside** a Pass-Through query. Its SQL gets sent as-is to the DB server, and that obviously doesn't know any local Access objects.

Comment: Barattolo_67, were you using Andre's technique when you said you tested it and it doesn't work? In my previous experience, I don't recall joining passthrough queries to local Access tables. I always dumped the passthrough results into local tables, and processed from there. As I recall, the column set of a passthrough is not defined in Access (you can put any SQL you please into it before executing it). A column set is dynamically generated when it executes, and you hope it matches what you have in the local destination table ;)